# Why does a function's derivative cross the x axis even though the function does not have an extreme point?

Tags: derivatives

My function: $(x+0.4)^2-\cos\left(1+\frac{\cos(x/2)}{\sin(x/2)}\right)$

My derived function: $0.8+2x+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sin(x/2)^2}\sin\left(1+\frac{\cos(x/2)}{\sin(x/2)}\right)$

Where $x$ is very close to $0.70825$, the derived function crosses the $x$ axis.

At first I thought it is not in the domain, but could not prove it to myself.

$$\begin{align}\sin(x/2)&\neq 0&\\x/2&\neq\pi/2 + \pi\cdot n,&n\in\mathbb{Z}\\x&\neq\pi + 2\pi n,&n\in\mathbb{Z}\end{align}$$

What is the problem here?

P.S: You can copy and look at graphs in http://www.mathe-fa.de/en#result

Comment: Your formula for the derivative is wrong.  The second $+$ should be $-$.

Comment: Thanks very much. Im still amused that the difference was so small.